# Smallest of three numbers using macro MINIMUM3

Tags: c, macros, numbers

I have to create a code that determines the smallest of three numeric values. 
Macro MINIMUM3 should use macro MINIMUM2 (the difference btwn two numeric values) to determine the smallest number. the input values come from the user input. I am not very familiar with using macros and my textbook doesn't really help in showing me an example of how they can work together to carry out their function. The code below is the work in progress that I have so far but I am running into errors on lines 3, 13, 16, and 20.

```
#define MINIMUM2 (a,b) (a < b ? a:b)

#define MINIMUM3 (a,b,c) (MINIMUM2(a,b) c? MINIMUM (a,b) :c)

int main (void) {
    int x,y,z;
    int temp; 
    printf("Please enter three numbers\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d, &x&y&z);
    temp = MIN(x,y,z);
    printf("The smallest number entered is:\n");
    printf("%d", &temp);
    getchar ();
    return0;
}
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: sorry, I must have forgot to include them. The line scanf- error stated invalid operands to binary &(have 'int *' and 'int')

Comment: The line scanf- error stated invalid operands to binary &(have 'int *' and 'int')                                                                                                                             The line temp = MIN (x,y,z) error stated implicit declaration of function 'MIN'                                                                                                               The line printf("%d", &temp); error stated invalid operands to binary & (have 'char *' and 'int')

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of issues in your code:

- `MINIMUM3` uses `MINIMUM` instead of `MINIMUM2`
- The logic of `MINIMUM3` is broken
- You need to remove spaces after macro names
- You are missing a closing double quote and commas in call of `scanf`
- You are using `MIN` in place of `MINUMUM3`
- You are passing an address of `temp` to `printf`

Here is how you can fix this:

```
#define MINIMUM2(a,b) (a < b ? a:b)
#define MINIMUM3(a,b,c) (MINIMUM2(MINIMUM2(a,b),c))

int main (void) {
    int x,y,z;
    int temp; 
    printf("Please enter three numbers\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &x, &y, &z);
    temp = MINIMUM3(x, y, z);
    printf("The smallest number entered is:\n");
    printf("%d", temp);
    getchar ();
    return0;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/dOSWMA)

You can improve your macros by enclosing each parameter in parentheses:

```
#define MINIMUM2 (a,b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

Comment: The errors I am running into now is ‘a’ undeclared (first use in this function) #define MINIMUM3 (a,b,c) (MINIMUM2(a, MINIMUM2(b,c)) ‘ 'b’ undeclared (first use in this function) #define MINIMUM3 (a,b,c) (MINIMUM2(a, MINIMUM2(b,c)) ‘c’ undeclared (first use in this function) #define MINIMUM3 (a,b,c) (MINIMUM2(a, MINIMUM2(b,c)) expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token temp = MINIMUM3 (x, y, z); ^

Comment: @thatguy That's because of spaces after macro names. They need to be removed. I spotted a few other problems, and added a link to a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of the `MINIMUM3` macro will lead to a syntax error. You should try something like

```
#define MINIMUM3(a, b, c) MINIMUM2(MINIMUM2(a, b), c)
```

or

```
#define MINIMUM3(a, b, c) MINIMUM2(a, MINIMUM2(b, c))
```

Also make sure to call `MINIMUM3` in `main`, not `MIN`.

Comment: I made the change you suggested nwellnhof as well as those from dasblinkin light.

Comment: The errors I am running into now is ‘a’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   #define MINIMUM3 (a,b,c) (MINIMUM2(a, MINIMUM2(b,c))                    ‘ 'b’ undeclared (first use in this function)                        
   #define MINIMUM3 (a,b,c) (MINIMUM2(a, MINIMUM2(b,c))                            ‘c’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   #define MINIMUM3 (a,b,c) (MINIMUM2(a, MINIMUM2(b,c))            expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
  temp =  MINIMUM3 (x, y, z);
                            ^